# Why is context in sigaction handler a void pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, sigaction

In `sigaction(2)` man page:

```
The siginfo_t argument to a SA_SIGINFO handler
   When the SA_SIGINFO flag is specified in act.sa_flags, the signal
   handler address is passed via the act.sa_sigaction field.  This han‐
   dler takes three arguments, as follows:

       void
       handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *ucontext)
       {
           ...
       }
```

Why is ucontext a `void *` when the man page states that it is a `ucontext_t *`?

```
ucontext
          This is a pointer to a ucontext_t structure, cast to void *.
          The structure pointed to by this field contains signal context
          information that was saved on the user-space stack by the ker‐
          nel; for details, see sigreturn(2).  Further information about
          the ucontext_t structure can be found in getcontext(3).  Com‐
          monly, the handler function doesn't make any use of the third
          argument.
```

Comment: Which `sigaction(2)` page are you referring to? One from a generic specification, or describing the behavior of a specific operating system?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/sigaction.html) actually requires this to be a `void *`, the third argument to `sigaction` is:

```
void(*) (int, siginfo_t *, void *)
```

Additionally, since a `void *` can be freely cast to and from any other sort of data pointer, there's little reason *not* to use the general case in a situation where you may want to seamlessly add different types in future.

Comment: Wouldn't that be an argument for never using the pointer for a type you know ahead of time? Why not always use void * then?

Comment: @Adam: because, in the general case, using `void *` prevents the compiler from catching type errors. For example, if you pass a pointer-to-four-byte-int to a function that treats it as an pointer-to-eight-byte-double and plays around with the underlying memory, you're going to get hit with undefined behaviour. The idea is to *prefer* type safety but just go around it when you need a pointer-to-arbitrary-type.

Comment: This answer seems to just push the question back a level - why does POSIX require the third argument to be `void *` instead of `ucontext_t *`?  Is there any concrete reason why the POSIX committee thought this specific argument needed type flexibility?

Comment: @zwol pretty much, especially when it is specified that it _will_ be type `ucontext_t *`.